# Something similar to yield break in F#

Tags: f#

How to break after first if?

```
let WithdrawalCash (account, amount) = seq {        

    if ( account.Balance.CurrentAmount - amount < 0.0m) then
        yield NotEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal(account, amount)   
        // How to break here?     

    let newBalance = account.Balance.CurrentAmount - amount
    yield CashWithdrawnEvent(account, newBalance)
}
```

Comment: Even though I appreciate the idea of breaking to reduce nesting and want to know the answer, won't else work?

Comment: @Martinho, I am kind newbie to F#. So if you have something in mind, pls, suggest.

Comment: I am learning F# as well and I'm waiting for someone to answer this (or maybe later I'll get some time to research this myself and answer it :). What I asked is if you can solve the problem by placing the remaining computation in an * `else` * clause. Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: Ah, `else` language construct... Funny, I read your message won't something else work :). In this situation `else` will work. But I need more general solution. Nested `if`s reduce readability.

Comment: If your nesting `if`s you should consider using active patterns. http://www.infoq.com/articles/Beyond-Foundations-FSharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this will help, why not use the else clause?

```
let WithdrawalCash (account, amount) = seq {        

   if ( account.Balance.CurrentAmount - amount < 0.0m) then
       yield NotEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal(account, amount)   
       // How to break here?     
   else 
      let newBalance = account.Balance.CurrentAmount - amount
      yield CashWithdrawnEvent(account, newBalance) 
}
```

Also have a look at:

[Imperative computation in F# (II.) - Writing break and continue](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-ii-break.aspx)

Comment: You can use "if" only in simple examples. For example if you will have few nested conditions, readability will fall down.

Comment: @primodemus, OK thanks I got your answer. Thanks. Links to hubFS was aye-openers.

Answer (score 3):

The code as posted will only evern return one CashWithdrawlEvent, then end the sequence... you need to have a loop to return multiple values.  Also, have you considered using "match" to handle multiple cases?

(not tested as working...)

```
let WithdrawalCash (account, amount) = seq {         

    let bDone = ref false

    while not (!bDone) do
        match amount with
        | v when account.Balance.CurrentAmount - v < 0 ->
           yield NotEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal(account, amount)
           bDone := true    // break

        // more when clauses can go here

        | _ ->
          let newBalance = account.Balance.CurrentAmount - amount 
          yield CashWithdrawnEvent(account, newBalance) 
          // let the sequence continue

}
```

But, even this does not seem like what you would want, since it will ALWAYS withdraw the same 'amount' each time you pull a value from the sequence, because account and amount are fixed when the sequence is created.  So, I'd drop the 'seq' and make this a simple function, as in:

```
let WithdrawalCash (account, amount) =

    match amount with
    | v when account.Balance.CurrentAmount - v < 0 ->
       NotEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal(account, amount)

    // more when clauses can go here

    | _ ->
      let newBalance = account.Balance.CurrentAmount - amount 
      CashWithdrawnEvent(account, newBalance)
```

For the general case of enumerating some sequence and stopping when a particular condition is met, consider "Seq.takeWhile", as in:

```
let MySeq = seq {
    while true do
        yield someValue
    }

let code () =
    MySeq
    |> Seq.takeWhile ( fun v -> ShouldIContinueWorkingTest(v) )
    |> Seq.iter ( fun v -> DoWork(v) )
```

Comment: Your answer is totally correct, but I am considered with readability.

Comment: Readibility in which way?  What is your concern?

Answer (score 0):

As this is the only relevant question in SO about `yield break` in F#, I think I should add this for the sake of completeness. In the OP's question one could get away with the `else`. But what do you do if you **really** need to break? what if you have to deal with `match`? Let's assume that you have a discriminated union like this

```
type SomeUnion =
    | Foo of SomeType
    | Bar of SomeType * SubclassOfSomeType
    | Indifferent of IncompatibleType
```

and you want to get a sequence of `SomeType` and `SubclassOfSomeType` and ignore the rest:

```
let private toSomeType (arg:SomeUnion) =
    seq {
        match arg with
        | Foo foo -> yield foo
        | Bar (one, two) -> yield one; yield two
        | Indifferent _ -> () (*<- effectively this is your 'yield break'*)
    }
```

I used `Indifferent` as it was my only remaining case. Obviously one could simply use `| _ -> ()` to ignore a gazillion of cases, I just prefer to see the warning if I add another case in the future.

I hope that this is a correct technique as I am an absolute beginner in F# and I had to chase my tail for some time to get around this. Feel free to let me know in the comments if there is a better way.